Using right prepositions

I will have done it ......

I will have been doing for 2 years ......


Now, I'd like to ask which points fits those two examples
A) "by next week" or just "next week" correct in both
B) "at 5" wrong in both we should say "by 5" then it is correct in both
C)"in January" fine in both
D) "On Monday" fine in both
E) "in a minute" fine in both
Am I mistaken somewhere?

(2) doesn't fit at all with B or E. No-one would speak of a two-year period ending at a certain time of day.

@KateBunting it just about 2 and examples B and E and the rest is fine?

Are the rest fine? We usually say "I will have done/finished it by" a future date, but in a period of time from now (e.g. a minute, half an hour).  For (2) - 'Two years next week/in January/on Monday'.

@KateBunting so A, B, C and E fit my example number 1. What about D? Can I say " I will have done it on Monday" and the meaning is almost the same if I just say "I will do it on Monday? Yes or no, why?

I will do it on Monday normally means that you will start and finish the job on Monday. I will have done it on Monday is an odd thing to say. It just means that, on that day, doing 'it' will be in the past. Far more natural to say I will have done it by Monday - you can guarantee that you will have finished 'it' by then.

@KateBunting what about in? For instance. "I will have done it in January"?

Exactly the same applies, of course!
